# Sorting array of numbers

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have some certain things which will be pushed into array like that (down below) and I would like to sort the item(s) by the item price. I tried using a `sort` but it doesn't work for me. After that I would like to loop that array and retrieve the item name and a item price.

Pushing item into array: `array.push(itemName,itemPrice)`

Trying to use `sort` function:

```
array.sort(function(a,b){
    return b[1] - a[1]
});
```

Comment: please add the array as well.

Comment: You will have to show us exactly what the array data is like so we can see how to sort it properly.  Your code is trying to sort an array of arrays.  `array.push(itemName,itemPrice)` puts two consecutive and separate values into the array.  It doesn't push an array into the array.  For that you would need `array.push([itemName,itemPrice])`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: Agree with Nina's comment. changing compare function

Looks like you need an array of objects and define your own comparison function for sorting.

So you need to add element to array like this:

```
array.push({itemName:name,itemPrice:price})
```

Define custom comparison function

```
function compare(a,b) {
  return a.itemPrice-b.itemPrice;
}
```

Use custom function

```
array.sort(compare)
```

Comment: you could use the delta, without the overhead of two comparisons.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to push the tuple (itemName, itemPrice) to array which can be done either way:

```
array.push([itemName, itemPrice])
```

or

```
array.push({ itemName: itemName, itemPrice: itemPrice })
// and instead of accessing a[1] or b[1], access a.itemPrice and b.itemPrice respectively.
```

**array.push(x, y)** simply appends two different elements x and y to the array

Answer (score 1):

I think what you want to do is push objects not just values!

```
array.push( { 
    name: itemName, 
    price: itemPrice 
} );
```

Which you can then sort using:

```
array.sort(function(a, b){
    return b.price - a.price;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

// Sort BY keys( and values).

```
    int[] keys = { 4, 7, 2, 0 };
    int[] values = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
    Array.Sort(keys, values);
    foreach (int key in keys)
    {
        Console.Write(key);
        Console.Write(' ');
    }
    Console.WriteLine();
    foreach (int value in values)
    {
        Console.Write(value);
        Console.Write(' ');
    }
    Console.WriteLine();
```

I hope this will help you ;)

Answer (score 0):

here is a sample code, have fun !

```js
var arr = [
 {
  "name": "Item1",
  "price": 100,
 },
 {
  "name": "Item2",
  "price": 500,
 },
 {
  "name": "Item3",
  "price": 250,
 },
 {
  "name": "Item4",
  "price": 1000,
 }
]


arr = arr.sort(function compare(a, b) {
  if (a.price > b.price)
     return 1;
  if (a.price < b.price)
     return -1;
  return 0;
});

console.log(arr);
```